# 3 DIVs, 1 Container, Centrally aligned horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

I've got three `DIV`s that I've put into a container `DIV`.

What I want is as follows:

[image: Demo image]

Here's where I'm up to:

```css
#light-table {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#leftdiv {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
  /*margin:20px 0;*/
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
#leftdivcontainer {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#light-table-paragraph {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="light-table">
  <h3 id="light-table-head-style">content.</h3>
  <div id="leftdivcontainer">
    <div id="leftdiv">
      <p id="light-table-paragraph">Left</p>
    </div>
    <div id="leftdiv">
      <p id="light-table-paragraph">Middle</p>
    </div>
    <div id="leftdiv">
      <p id="light-table-paragraph">Right</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please can someone help tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: Hey @Scott Davies - for starters, replace `id` with `class` in your HTML, and `#` for `.` in your CSS for those elements you have more than one of, so `light-table-paragraph` and `leftdiv`

Comment: Thank you, I will revise the usage. Can you tell I'm new to this? haha.

Comment: you have to start somewhere :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

Give each .leftdiv (indeed this should be a class, id's are unique) 33% of total viewport width:

```
.leftdiv {
  float: left;
  width: 33%; 
}
```

and center each paragraph inside these divs, give it 75% width:

```
.leftdiv p {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto !important; /* you won't need !important if your code is well structured */
}
```

This is a cleaner solution, as you'll notice there is no horizontal scroll present.

[Here](http://codepen.io/fredrocha/pen/GrwEpe) is a codepen.

Also, you need to clear your parent div #leftdivcontainer (did that as well).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much that worked a charm.  I appreciate it!

Comment: Cool, @ScottDavies, glad I could help! Did you consider the accepted answer to be better? Don't forget to share the project once it's live. ;)

Comment: Perhaps I accepted an answer by mistake - I'm new to the forum so I upvoted a couple of things because people took time from their life to help me :)

It's live at http://scott.ewarena.com/blog but it's still a Work In Progress :)

Comment: Well, yeah, Stackoverflow is THE place to come to when in programming need! :)

Thanks for accepting my answer, and keep hacking away at your new site. You're getting there!

Comment: Yeah man, it looks so much better than it did like a week ago! I've also just hidden the video play button on iOS devices from ANOTHER thread I found on here via google, so that was super-helpful.  I just need to get the other pages sorted now, and get some content on there!

Answer (score 2):

set the div the contains the three small divs `display:flex` and give it 75% width of the container, then set space around the content as follow:

```css
#leftdiv {
    /*float: left;*/
    padding:0 20px; 
    /*margin:20px 0;*/
    position:relative;
    /* edits */
    width:33.33%;
    flex-basis: 25%; 
}

#leftdivcontainer {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
    /* edits */
    width:75%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px auto;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#light-table-paragraph {
    font-family: 'Droid Serif';
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    text-align: left;
    line-height:40px;
}

#light-table {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;  
    width: 100%;  
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="light-table">
     <h3 id="light-table-head-style">content.</h3>
    <div id="leftdivcontainer">
    <div id="leftdiv"><p id="light-table-paragraph">Left</p></div>
    <div id="leftdiv"><p id="light-table-paragraph">Middle</p></div>
    <div id="leftdiv"><p id="light-table-paragraph">Right</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, was just about to say :) Add `display: flex; justify-content: space-around;` to the container :) @Scott, also fix the duplicated `id`s.